# Can't make an account on civicrm.org to use with gitlab

Tags: civicrm.org, gitlab

I want to log an issue on gitlab and it says to create an account. So I go to https://civicrm.org/user/register and fill in various details but there is nowhere to create a password. The form submits without error but when I go to "forgot password" tells me the account does not exist. If I try to create the same account again however, it tells me that the name and email address are already registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, turns out it just took a long time to get a confirmation email. Once I got that and clicked the link it allowed me to set a password.

Comment: Naomi - can you accept/tick your own answer to help close this off?

Comment: Not till tomorrow apparently!

Comment: ok. thx for explaining that to me.